# Redirect to homepage if file or directory doesn't exist using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I am Hosting a domain on free hosting site 000webhost, I want to redirect all files or folder that doesn't exist to my homepage. The Code, I have used is:

```
RewriteEngine on
rewritecond %{http_host} ^domain\.com$ [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [r=301,l]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.html$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.html
```

1. It works, but the url doesn't change to homepage. Like if I am trying to open `www.domain.com/blaa` it redirects me to home page but the URL is still `www.domain.com/blaa`. I want it to be changed to `www.domain.com`.
2. If I am trying to open a valid directory, which exist in my root folder, it also redirects to homepage. Like if I am trying to open `www.domain.com/folder`, it should result in files and directories in that folder, instead of that it redirects me to homepage and web address is still same like `www.domain.com/folder`.

Also I want to keep using the above 2 rules to open website with WWW and index.html with www.domain.com

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As per your questions's title, to redirect to homepage if the request is not for a file or dir, you can use :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ / [L]
```

You can also use ErrorDocument directive to rewrite non-existent requests to homepage

```
ErrorDocument 404 /
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply, i appreciate it. The code you have suggested me it works but still the url doesn't change to homepage it keeps the same i have typed. Like if i am trying to open www.domain.com/blaa and of course it doesn't exist in my directory, it's redirecting me to homepage but the url still the same www domain.com/blaa. Can it be changed to www.domain.com ? And one more thing that i have hjust noticed if i type .com twice after domain name it directs me to 404 000webhost page.